# Resize the renderer in highcharts through mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have drawn a renderer in high-charts using the mouse events . I want to resize and drag&drop the drawn renderer,since I couldn't get a way to resize the drawn renderer I have statically created a html div element with jquery and used some plugins from jquery to resize and drag&drop the drawn element and passing the resized and dragged value from the jquery div element to the renderer in high-charts so the the high-charts renderer gets dragged to the exact position where the html div element is dragged by the user. can anyone help to achieve this only through high-charts?? I have used mouse events  to draw in high charts but i cannot get resize and draggable options for drawn renderer, Please look to this fiddle to see what I have done..[jsfiddle](`click here`https://jsfiddle.net/vgokul2272/ecqL1nw7/3/). you can notice on drag and drop of the grey box ,a yellow box behind the grey box.grey box is the html div element and yellow box is the renderer in highcharts.

Comment: try calling $('.dummyBox').highcharts(); again when you resize the box.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the thing is i dont want to use jquery here..i want that to happen through high charts alone

Comment: What do you mean you can not get resize and draggable options? 1) For drag&drop add events (`mousedown`, `mousemove`, `moueup`) where you will store rect (mousedown), translate rect(mousemove if there is stored rect)  and release rect (mouseup). 2) For resize, logic is almost the same, just you need to create four another rects which will get mouse events (`mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup`).

Comment: Thank you very much@Pawel Fus. that really helped a lot..